# Copy and paste a row based on a cell's value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this sheet: https://puu.sh/ISskB/7329c743ce.png

Basically all I want is to copy and paste all rows which contain column F2:F1000>20% into another sheet. I am planning to schedule this script to run one time per day, so it should not override any data pasted in previous days.

Thanks

Comment: If you have no knack in scripting you can do this via filtering your data. Just common filter in the column F, and Ctrl+C, Ctlr+V then. Nothing fancy. Why do you need a script?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply! I want this to be automatic every day that's why I need a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```
function set_trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("main").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
}

function main() {
  copy_all_rows_to_dest_sheet();
  remove_redundant_rows();
}

function copy_all_rows_to_dest_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var src_range = src_sheet.getDataRange();
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(dest_sheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  src_range.copyTo(dest_range);
}

function remove_redundant_rows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // get indexes of redundant rows
  var rows = data.map(x => x.slice(0,-1).join());
  var indexes = [];
  var i = 0;
  while (rows.length) {
    var row = rows.shift();
    // var percent = data[i].pop();
    var percent = data[i][5];   // <---------------------- update
    if (percent < .2 || rows.includes(row)) indexes.push(i);
    i++;
  }

  // remove the rows by the indexes
  while (indexes.length) sheet.deleteRow(indexes.pop()+1);
}
```

If you run the function `set_trigger()` it will run the function `main()` every day.

The function `main()` copies all the rows from the sheet 'Sheet1' at the end of the sheet 'Sheet2' and removes all the duplicated rows and all the rows that have value in the last column less than 20%.

**Update**

Here is the variant of the main function that doesn't keep a formatting (it takes all formatting from the destination sheet):

```
function main_no_formatting() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var src_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var src_range = src_sheet.getDataRange();
  var [header, ...src_data] = src_range.getValues();
  
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getDataRange();
  var [_, ...dest_data] = dest_range.getValues();

  var data = [...src_data, ...dest_data];
  var rows = data.map(x => x.join());
  var filtered_data = [];

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = rows.shift();
    var percent = data[i][5];
    if (percent < .2) continue;
    if (rows.includes(row)) continue;
    filtered_data.push(data[i])
  }

  var table = [header, ...filtered_data];
  
  dest_sheet.clear();
  dest_sheet.getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

Be careful with `%` signs. If they disappear from the destination sheet the code wont work.

My sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxTQcLao_p13QCXqCli0nsi12MKjzvMWIGD7OcYjRqQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hello thank you for your time and efford! However, i just tried the script and it just copy paste all data to Sheet2 except the 100% value ones. Here is a gif with my test: https://puu.sh/ISEIN/bf186f8388.gif

Comment: Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxTQcLao_p13QCXqCli0nsi12MKjzvMWIGD7OcYjRqQ/edit?usp=sharing You can try it, it works fine with my dummy data. The code is quite trivial. Obviously there are some things in your spreadsheet that break the code. Perhaps the formatting of some cells, etc. It's need to tweak it somehow. If you share an example of your sheet I can try to fix is. This is exactly why a simply no code solution often is a good idea. And this is exactly why to provide a reproducible example or/and a real data is a good idea as well.

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't work for you. I've thought that the percent column (F) is a last column in the table (based on the screenshot in your question). The line `var percent = data[i].pop();` takes value from a last column. But since column F is not a last one you have to change the line this way: `var percent = data[i][5];`

Comment: You're right! It worked now! Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question, what i have to change in your code to make it copy paste values only? Not formulas etc. Also is there any way to improve speed performance? It takes more than 15 seconds to finish the script.

Comment: Well, the implementation is slow because it tries to keep all formatting intact (font colors, backgrounds, etc, and the formulas as well). It literally copies all the rows and removes the redundant ones, one by one. The removing is quite slow operation. You can significantly improve the speed if you don't need to keep the formatting. It will be a quite different algorithm.

Comment: Sure, i don't need formatting. Just copy paste values. What would I have to change in code?

Comment: I've added the updated version of the main function.

Comment: I suddenly thought, probably it will be better to use `dest_sheet.clearContents();` instead of `dest_sheet.clear();`.

Comment: Better in terms of?

Comment: It wont clear formatting of the cells. You can format the empty sheet (font color, background) and it will keep it intact.

Comment: It works! Thanks for this suggestion/improvement!